# Youtube playlist is unrecognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pafy

Im trying to set a radio and youtube playlist player

my code works with radio and single youtube link but with playlist it says that the link is unrecognized, can somoene help?

```
import os
from os import path
from random import randrange
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import pafy
import requests
import vlc
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,PhotoImage

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = Tk()

global phplay,phpause,phstop
global pausevar
pausevar = ""
phplay = PhotoImage(file=r'img/play.png')
phpause = PhotoImage(file=r'img/pause.png')
phstop = PhotoImage(file=r'img/stop.png')


frmradio = LabelFrame(root, text="Radio Player", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
frmradio.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW, pady=2)



def getradiolist():
    var1 = open("Confs/lstradios.txt", "r").readlines()
    data = []

    for line in var1:
        if len(line) > 1:
            estacao, url, = line.split('<=>')
            data.append(estacao)
    return data

valradio = StringVar()
imp_radio = Combobox(frmradio, textvariable=valradio, height=10, width=47)
imp_radio['values'] = getradiolist()
imp_radio['state'] = 'readonly'
imp_radio.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=5, pady=2, sticky="ew")

# define VLC instance
instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen')
# Define VLC player
player = instance.media_player_new()
instance.log_unset()


def startplayer(pausevar):
    if pausevar == "sim":
        pausevar=""
        player.pause()


    player.stop()
    esta = imp_radio.get()
    if len(esta)>1:
        var1 = open("Confs/lstradios.txt", "r").readlines()
        for line in var1:
            if len(line) > 1:
                if esta in line:
                    estacao, url, = line.split('<=>')
                    break

        if "youtube" in estacao:

            playlist = pafy.get_playlist(url)
            items = playlist["items"]# getting playlist items
            def loop_play():
                item = items[randrange(len(items))]
                i_pafy = item['pafy']
                y_url = i_pafy.watchv_url
                video = pafy.new(y_url)
                best = video.getbest()
                media = instance.media_new(best.y_url.strip())  # por testar ainda
                player.set_media(media)
                frmradio.config(text=str(playlist["title"]))
                player.play()

            loop_play()
        else:
            media = instance.media_new(url.strip())
            player.set_media(media)
            player.play()


        frmradio.config(text=str("Radio Player : Playing: " + estacao))


def stopplauyer():
    player.stop()
    frmradio.config(text=str("Radio Player"))

def pauseplauyer():
    global pausevar
    pausevar = "sim"
    player.pause()
    frmradio.config(text=str("Radio Player : Pause!"))



Button(frmradio, width="150",height="28", text="Play", image=phplay, command=lambda pausevar=pausevar: startplayer(pausevar)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
Button(frmradio, width="100",height="28", text="Pause", image=phpause, command=lambda: pauseplauyer()).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + S + E + W)
Button(frmradio, width="100",height="28", text="Stop", image=phstop,command=lambda: stopplauyer()).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

getting this error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py",
> line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/ricardosimoes/PycharmProjects/OCPP/yplayer.py", line 105, in
>
> Button(frmradio, width="150",height="28", text="Play", image=phplay, command=lambda pausevar=pausevar:
> startplayer(pausevar)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
> File "/Users/ricardosimoes/PycharmProjects/OCPP/yplayer.py", line 70,
> in startplayer
> playlist = pafy.get_playlist2(url)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pafy/playlist.py",
> line 316, in get_playlist2
> return Playlist.from_url(playlist_url, basic, gdata, size, callback)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pafy/playlist.py",
> line 175, in from_url
> t = cls(url,  basic, gdata, size, callback)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pafy/playlist.py",
> line 146, in **init**
> raise ValueError(err % playlist_url) ValueError: Unrecognized playlist url:
> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLr5JVJSLVg79UpgS6gdrcINWt86npzXkz

Listaradios.txt is

youtube  <=> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLr5JVJSLVg79UpgS6gdrcINWt86npzXkz

Mega Hits <=> http://19553.live.streamtheworld.com:80/MEGA_HITS_SC

Comment: Use `get_playlist2` instead of `get_playlist`.

Comment: Thanks Marco but still have the same error

Comment: Can you add the error? - I'm trying your code and I get other response.

Comment: too long for here, going to add it to the post

Comment: Thanks, try then adding only the playlist id - example: `PLr5JVJSLVg79UpgS6gdrcINWt86npzXkz`. If you want, you can use Google Colaboratory for create a working sample - as I did [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gjgPR9FOc3FWt_WFk0FNeZG6flNEfMnF?usp=sharing) while trying to help you.

Comment: same thing :( ValueError: Unrecognized playlist url:  PLr5JVJSLVg79UpgS6gdrcINWt86npzXkz

Comment: didnt know colaboratory, thanks, will check it better tonight

Comment: got it, it was a space in the url, passed url.strip() and error gone.

Comment: now got: pafy.util.GdataError: Youtube Error 403: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.      :(

Comment: I'm glad you found the error with the URL. I got the same quota error :( my best guess is to keep searching how you can set your own API KEY to pafy or search another tool. I really can't help you further with pafy - as I searched, I think pafy is not currently in development - but, again, this is my impression.